# Storage of entangled particles

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I have been trying to find the answer to these questions on the net but have had no luck. 
Can entangled particles be stored? Can an entangled particle be repeatedly measured?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please give some indication of your background knowledge? Have you had a course in quantum mechanics?

Comment: No background in particle physics. I have been studying the big and small universe through YouTube for a little over 3 years. I have many thoughts and some questions that I just haven't been able to find the answer no the net. I came across this blog / sites and thought to try my luck. Do you by any chance know the answer to my questions or another place / way to find the answer?

Comment: The answer to your question lies in quantum mechanics, because entanglement is a short hand word to describe correlations between particles at the quantum mechanical level. As quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory, one needs many instances of situations to be able to predict. One has to understand how quantum numbers and their conservation can carry information at the quantum level.  Also one has to define what it means by storage at that level. Each measurement changes the quantum mechanical state, for example, because it is an interaction, . the quantum rules differ from  classical.

Comment: The question is ongoing research  https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07774 , you need qm to go further.

Comment: Here  are links to earlier papers of a system https://www.technologyreview.com/s/420664/physicists-build-a-memory-that-stores-entanglement/